# Django add RunSQL operation after adding ForeignKey constraint in migration

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

I'm using **Django 2.1**, **Python 3.6** and **MySQL 8**.

The database has quite huge table with plenty of big rows, hence migration applied to this table takes hours to complete. I discovered if I remove *fulltext index* from this table it enables *inplace alghorithm* of modyfing table - it's muuuch faster.

So I need to take advantage of that in Django.
I thought about removing *fulltext index* as first migration operation and create it again after all other operations.

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='NewModel',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
        options={
            'abstract': False,
        },
    ),
    migrations.RunSQL(
        ('DROP INDEX fulltext_idx_content ON summarizer_model',),
        ('CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext_idx_content ON summarizer_model(content)',),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='model',
        name='new_model',
        field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='new_models_objects', to='summarizer.new_model'),
    ),
    migrations.RunSQL(
        ('CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext_idx_content ON summarizer_model(content)',),
        ('DROP INDEX fulltext_idx_content ON summarizer_model',),
    ),
]
```

(I quickly 'anonymized' above code snipper, so if there is some logical error then please excuse me - this is not the case here :) )

The problem is that Django migration always put adding ForeignKey constraint as last operation. So after my last `RunSQL` which creates index back. It makes it very slow operation (copy whole table with new column).

Is there a way to overcome it? It would be strange to put another migration file just for index creation I guess. I would simply like to temporary delete index for the time of migration.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I digged into the internals of Django migrations I discovered that some migration operations in Django add SQLs to so called `deferred_sql` list in schema object.
So knowing that fix to my problem was to inherit from `RunSQL` operation.
Instead of executing SQL immediately I append it to `deferred_sql` list and... that's it!

```
class DeferredForwardRunSQL(RunSQL):
def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
    schema_editor.deferred_sql.append(self.sql[0])
```

I needed to also modify last RunSQL operation from migration:

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='NewModel',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
        options={
            'abstract': False,
        },
    ),
    migrations.RunSQL(
        ('DROP INDEX fulltext_idx_content ON summarizer_model',),
        ('CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext_idx_content ON summarizer_model(content)',),
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='model',
        name='new_model',
        field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='new_models_objects', to='summarizer.new_model'),
    ),
    DeferredForwardRunSQL(
        ('CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fulltext_idx_content ON summarizer_model(content)',),
        ('DROP INDEX fulltext_idx_content ON summarizer_model',),
    ),
]
```

Works well also for backwards